# Generate projects dependencies structure diagrams

Tags: java, uml, generator

I would like to generate a diagram to show my projects structure. Preferably the generator will include referenced projects defined in build-path. There is such generator or Eclipse plugin? I know UMLet and UML2 allow drawing these kind of diagrams, but I would like them to be generated automatically.

I am not looking for class diagrams.

If it is an Eclipse plugin it should work with Kepler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Eclipse Project Dependencies Viewer": http://epdv.googlecode.com/

It really is very simple to use, works fine with Kepler and conveys the project hierarchy at a glance.

Comment: wayback leads you to: http://web.archive.org/web/20160210063203/https://code.google.com/archive/p/epdv

Which then points you to: 

https://code.google.com/archive/p/epdv/

You are welcome !!!11

So, it must have been discontinued somewhere since 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are a few plugins for Eclipse that can generate UML from Java code. Try [this one](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.umlgen) or simply Google "java generate uml"

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've googled it of course, but I can only find class diagram generators. Also none of them seem to be easy to use. For example, I've just installed Acceleo, but I can't find an option 'new Diagram', I can only create a Acceleo project or Acceleo module, documentation is insufficient. It should be as simple as clicking on the source folder and then 'Generate Package Diagram'